# Linux mp3 player with specific requirements, especially: playlists with ability to resume for audiobooks

Tags: linux, software-rec, mp3, music, playlists

I'm looking for mp3 player (software), running on Linux, but I need one specific option: it needs to be able to remember my position of listening in a given playlist.

Scenario:
I'm creating a playlist. Adding to it X files. Play them. After some time, I switch to another playlist - in the middle of some song from playlist 1. After some more time, I go back to playlist 1, and it resumes playing from exactly the same spot it was before. Perfect for audiobooks.

If this software would also **not** do stuff like "manage your collection" - it would be absolutely great. I personally hate all those "collection managing" players, because scanning collection takes long time, and I have it already well organized using directories and file names, and don't care about what's being scanned out of mp3 tags.

Is there anything like this?

Comment: There are currently 2 votes to close as "too localized". While I see that it's localized, I think it's actually perfectly good question for very simple reason - the main feature I ask about (playlist with ability to resume) is for audiobooks. So it's not very esoteric use-case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amarok should be able do what you ask. You can also manually add bookmarks to mark where you want it to resume from. Just don't use the collections manager.

Comment: I somehow never realized that Amarok had a way to play files without using collection! Thanks a lot, it solved my problem.